# How to plot a 100x100 data set with circles of different colors with image command in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dat file test.dat with 100 rows and 100 columns in it. The data are only numbers , 0 to 5. Now I want to plot this data in Gnuplot with **matrix with image** command. The commands are given below

```
    set size square
    set palette model RGB defined (0 "dark-pink", 1 "yellow", 2 "brown", 3 "red", 4 "green", 5 "blue")
    set cbrange [0:5]
    unset colorbox
    plot [1:100] [1:100] "test.dat" matrix with image
```

But the problem is that in the plot the data are displayed in squares of different colors. I want the this data will appear as circles of different colors.

Answer (score 1):

Simply plot it as `matrix with points` and `pointtype 7`.

**Code:**

```
### plot a matrix with points
reset session

N = 100
# create some test data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:N] {
        Line = ''
        do for [j=1:N] {
            Line = Line.sprintf(" %d",int(rand(0)*6))
        }
        print Line
    }
set print

set size square
set palette model RGB defined (0 "dark-pink", 1 "yellow", 2 "brown", 3 "red", 4 "green", 5 "blue")
set cbrange [0:5]
unset colorbox
set tics out
set xrange[0:N+1]
set xtics 10
set mxtics 10
set yrange[0:N+1]
set ytics 10
set mytics 10

plot $Data u ($1+1):($2+1):3 matrix with p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: How many rows & columns are there in the generated data ?

Comment: ... `do for [i=1:100] ...`  So 100 rows and 100 columns. Apparently, it is plotted from 0 to 99.

Comment: Yes this code work fine. Thank you . Another question is , u 1:2:3 , what does it mean and how can I see the data file created by this code ?

Comment: it's not a file on disk but a datablock in memory. To show the datablock type `print $Data`. 1 is the column and 2 the row (or the other way around, not 100% sure, you need to test). 3 is the value itself. Check `help matrix`.

Comment: Thanks again. I plot the same thing from a .dat file also . works fine. But problem is that the x-axis & y-axis also contain extra points ( in your plot also ). How can excludes these points from the axes ?

Comment: what do you mean with extra points? There are 100x100 points, plotted from 0 to 99, so the first row and the first column are on top of the axis. You can shift them if needed. I will modify the code.

Comment: Yes . I also  get the shifted point in the plot. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Yes, the question is answered. Thanks

Comment: then please check it as accepted in order to indicate that your question has been answered.